# Change "Error" color in SublimeREPL for Sublime Text 3

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I am using R in SublimeREPL for Sublime Test 3. Is there a way to change the color encoding for the "Error" output in the SublimeREPL console? Basically if I run a block of code, I need to easily be able to scroll through it to see if there was an error, but right now it encodes the error line identical to a normal text line (as opposed to the R gui, which shows all errors as bright red). Is there a way to change this?